# Power BI: Data value based on few tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, nested-if

I need to model data related with studying people (or potential students).

All the contact data with unique ID is stored in one table, contacts who are interested in studying (filled form, are completing documents, etc.) until they sign the contract for studying are stored in table with "Candidates" where single contact may appear more then once (ex. few specializations). When someone will sign the contract new entry will be created (linked by contact ID) in "Students" table, where again one contact may study on more then one course or have finished one earlier and is now taking another - it will have different DIDACTICS status then; which will again lead to one to many relation.

I need to be able to count and show in one place (preferably in form of funnel) amount of people at each stage (preferably also indicate amount of duplicated entries): Prospect -> Interested -> Candidate -> Student depending on conditions:
- Prospect will just exist in contacts, 
- Interested will have date of form submission
- Candidate will have date of confirmation and status collecting documents
[Those can be found in table related with Candidates]
- Student will have contract signed and one of few statuses of didactics
(here I have problem with IF statement which has to check if DIDACTICS status is one of statuses in other table where STUDENT = True, because of situation where one ID may have few statuses)
- None of the statuses above should have Resignation date filled (maybe except Prospect)

When I'll have the counts for each group (later on they will be segmented inside each group by profile of client), I want to present it as funnel with additional information about CONVERSION rate (%) between each funnel segment.

Any ideas how to deal with it?

Thank you in advance, You're always amazing.

P.S.
For now i have added column nested IF which almost work, except:

> A single value for column 'Didactics_Status__c' in table 'Rekrutacja'
>   cannot be determined.

It goes like this:

```
onPath = IF(ISBLANK(MIN(Rekrutacja[Resignation_Date__c]));
    IF(NOT(Rekrutacja[Didactics_Status__c] IN {"break in education";"dean's leave";"OK";"resit";"semester start in progress";"transferred"});
        IF(NOT(ISBLANK(MIN(Rekrutacja[Signed_Contract_Date__c])));
            IF(NOT(ISBLANK(MIN(Rekrutacja[Confirmation_Date__c])));
                IF(NOT(ISBLANK(MIN(Rekrutacja[Enrollment_Date__c])));
                    "Interested";
                    "Prospect")
                ;"Candidate")
            ;"Contracted")
        ;"Student")
        ;"Resigned")
```

Comment: Can you provide any sample data and example(s) of what your desired outcome is/are? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have the columns figured out. Just need to be able to count the amount of students at each stage.

Create a calculated column and just do =SUM(xyz) for each.
If you need conditions, nest it inside the SUM.

Alternatively to nesting if statements, I would do a case/switch. It looks better.

```
Month = SWITCH('Table1'[CalendarMonth], 
    1, "January",
    2, "February",
    3, "March",
    4, "April",
    5, "May",
    6, "June",          
    7, "July",  
    8, "August",  
    9, "September",  
    10, "October",    
    11, "November",
    12, "December"
)
```

To create a funnel, you're going to need to have the overall amount of students. Should just be a count of the IDs.

Then you take your SUM and divide it by the total count of IDs.